# How to use winmerge as the merge/diff tool for git installed on Linux

Tags: git, winmerge, git-difftool

```
$ cd testGit/
$ ls
first.txt  second.txt
$ git log --oneline
9c88fb7 add second lines to 1st & 2nd files
9c3da6c add 1st & 2nd files

$ git diff 9c88fb7 9c3da6c first.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in first.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
diff --git a/first.txt b/first.txt
index 4a0143f..9c59e24 100644
--- a/first.txt
+++ b/first.txt
@@ -1,2 +1 @@
 first
-first2

$ git difftool HEAD HEAD~1
/git/2.5.3/git-core/mergetools/winmerge: line 124: /c/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe: No such file or directory
/git/2.5.3/git-core/mergetools/winmerge: line 124: /c/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe: No such file or directory
```

I have mounted the redhat drive to Z:/testGit/.

**Question** Can I use winmerge to do the comparison on the two commits(i.e. 9c88fb7 9c3da6c)?

Answer (score 1):

WinMerge is developed for Windows.

[From their site](http://winmerge.org/about/):

> WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows.

Also:

> Supports Microsoft Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008/7/8/2012

Here is a site with links to alternative diff tools for Linux:
http://www.linuxalt.com/linux-alternatives-to/windows/winmerge.html